# Flutter Error : The getter 'iterator' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter

How can i get list of image from firestore on flutter

i want to get list of image from firestore but i get following error:

**My error:**
The getter 'iterator' was called on null.

** my code**

```
return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: _store.load_item(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Item> _item = [];
          for (var doc in snapshot.data.docs) {
            var data = doc.data();

            List<String> image = [];
            List.from(data['item_colors']).forEach((element) {
              String data = element;
              image.add(data);
            });
            _item.add(Item(
              admin_id: data['admin_id'],
              item_id: data['item_id'],
              item_description: data['item_description'],
              item_price: data['item_price'],
              images: image,
            ));
          }
          return GridView.builder(
            itemCount: _item.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  Image(image: NetworkImage(_item[index].images.toString()))
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return Center(child: Text("Loading....."));
        }
      }),
);
```

**stream:**

```
 Stream<QuerySnapshot> load_item() {
final User user = auth.currentUser;
return firestore
    .collection("items")
    .where('admin_id', isEqualTo: user.uid)
    .snapshots();
```

}

Comment: Please add the error log here.

Comment: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#4f703):